# SyntaxError: [stdin]:6:2: unexpected {

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to add some Javascript to my rails apps. i want to hide my comment in the post area

post/index

```
<%= link_to "Comment", "#", id: "comment-link " %>
                  <section id="comment-section">

                    <%= render 'commenters/newsfeedcomment', obj: post %>

                    <% if current_user == post.user %>
                      <h6 align="right"><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></h6>
                      <h6 align="right"><%= link_to 'Delete', { :id => post ,:controller => 'posts',:action => 'destroy'} %></h6>
                    <% end %>
                  </section>
```

css

```
#comment-section{
display: none;
```

}

commenters.coffee

```
${document}.on "page:change", ->
$('#comment-link').click ->
    alert "clicked"
```

then when i want to try my Comment link if its working this error give me
[image]

Comment: Typo? `$(document).on`

Comment: thanks man i'm new in JS and i really want to learn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You have syntax error in your coffee script**

Do this:

```
$(document).on "page:change", ->
  $('#comment-link').click ->
    alert "clicked"
```

Instead of:

```
${document}.on "page:change", ->
$('#comment-link').click ->
    alert "clicked"
```

**Remember, indentation is most important while writing coffee script**

Comment: hi there pradeep sapkota your very active here. my i ask where can learn more in JS?

Comment: Actually I'm not a Academically studied programmer. Resource in internet are fine. If you found answer right for you please accept it and vote. That will keep me helping. Thank you.

Comment: vote is for 15 reputation only and i have 10 in accept 7 mins cooldown before i accept dont you worry i will accept your answer your very helpfull thanks :*

Comment: Now how did it reached.